# Stacked column graph with multiple entries per category

Tags: excel, ms-access, charts, stacked-chart, vba

I think that I am dealing with a special type of graph:
[image: SO29525280 question example]

I've researched stacked column graphs but they will only allow one series (type) entry per category (A,B,C).

Is there a way to display this using Excel/Access PivotCharts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional series by editing the existing series within the chart. When setting the additional series you get to pick the cell ranges for the series.

Comment: The problem is though I want non-contiguous range in the same series under the same label.  So category A has two type 2 series "ranges".  I think the problem is that there is no such thing as "ranges" with these type of charts so I am open to other suggestions as a way to go about this.

Comment: Filter the data to your non-contiguous range, then copy the range to a blank sheet. Do the same for each non-Contiguous range, then base your chart of the new sheet. You can use your macro recorder to save your filter criteria and construct the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you let yourself be a little flexible about data layout etc, you can get what you want. You may need multiple ranges for each Type, which means you get multiple series in the chart for each Type, which you then must format as all series of that Type.

Comment: So you mean like Type 1a, 1b, 1c... ect?  The problem I have is there are about 5 types, 10 "ranges" of varying types in each category, and 2000 categories.